# Why do some accounts have a profile picture with a crossed-out, grey human figure?

Tags: discussion, users, profile-picture

Normally, accounts on SO either have a profile pic that’s set by the user or a geometrical shape like the following:

[image]

However, on some accounts, I’ve seen the following symbol in place of the profile pic:

[image]

Example of such an account: [Example Account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14483536/jittu-varghese)

Is there any particular reason behind using this symbol in place of the profile pic?

Comment: See: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224634/what-does-grayed-slashed-icon-in-google-hangouts-mean

Comment: IIRC there's also the version without the strike-through. That happens for users who signed up with their Facebook account and other users (e.g. me) having certain ad or cookie blockers.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That particular picture is used for deactivated Google accounts. If you sign up through Google, you will get the option to use either the geometric Gravatar image or your Google account image. The picture might have happened if someone used Google to sign up for Stack Exchange, and they selected to use their Google picture, but then later their Google account got deleted.

Comment: This happened to me  ...  https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/94289/user10186832